# Git credential manager and manually created PAT

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-credential-manager, azure-repos

I have to work from computers owned by customer. Our work's code is managed under a Azure Dev Ops repository, where I log in using my personal Microsoft Account.

In order to reduce risk, I created a personal account with minimal rights within my Azure Devops dashboard.

How can I setup git to use this PAT without prompting for my Microsoft Account ?

Right now, each time a remote operation is triggered, a modal opens, asking for username/password.
If I close it, it reopens. I close again and I can enter my PAT. This is working.

But if I trigger a new remote operation, same sequences occurs (have to close twice the credential dialog, then pasting the PAT).

How can I store the PAT definitively ?

FYI, I've ensure the correct helper is set within git global config, as [suggested by the FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/blob/master/Docs/Faq.md) : `git config credential.helper manager`

I also tried to disable the credential helper with `git config --system --unset credential.helper`, but the issue is still present.

Another try was to use another helper : `git config credential.helper store`. Not better

FYI: I'm running on windows 2012R2, with the latest git version (`git version 2.20.1.windows.1`)

Comment: Try editing your global git config and set `[credential]helper=`, leave it empty. Then delete your credential from the Windows Credential store.

Comment: @jessehouwing: it actually works. You should post this as an answer to get reward. That said, wht is puzzling me is that I don't have to type any password. Even if I delete stored credentials. Now, where PAT is supposed to be stored ?

Comment: No clue... Are you logged on in windows with this account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your global git config and leave the helper empty.

```
 [credential]
      helper=
```

Then delete your credential from the Windows Credential store.

That should turn off the credential helper and revert to the default git behavior.